# Netbeans 8.2 code completion for CSS font-family

Tags: css, netbeans, font-family

I am using Netbeans 8.2 and finding it generally great... however, when coding CSS font-family there is a very limited code completion list (sans-serif, serif, etc.). I have to fully type Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;. Am I missing something? I have only the HTML5/PHP install.
If using Visual Studio Code the code completion for font-family is working.
Thanks in advance for any light you can shed on this.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing something?

No. I have a full install of NetBeans and get the same result as you.

> If using Visual Studio Code the code completion for font-family **is
>   working**.

Well that depends on what you mean by "*is working*"...

A **font-family** name can be a **family-name** or a **generic-family**.

The **generic-family** names [are formally defined](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#propdef-font-family) ("serif", "sans-serif", "cursive", "fantasy", "monospace"), and those are provided as options in NetBeans with code completion:

[image]

However, **family-name** is defined as "*the name of a font family of choice*", meaning you pick a font that you want your web page(s) to use. Given that there are thousands of available fonts, NetBeans cannot know what specific fonts to provide during code completion for **font-family**. It has no idea what operating system or browser your application is going to use (and you may not either). And even if NetBeans did know the target environment, it would still not be able to provide a guaranteed list of safe fonts during code completion.

Of course [some fonts are more popular than others](http://bonfx.com/fonts-of-the-world/) so I suppose you could raise a bug report with NetBeans suggesting that they offer some additional font names on code completion based on popularity, but the process would be very subjective, and different people would would come up with a different lists.

I also checked what Eclipse and Intellij IDEA do for code completion for **font-family**. Eclipse is the same as NetBeans, offering only the **generic-family** names, but Itellij IDEA offers a huge list of fonts:

[image: intellijIdeaFontFamily]

I am running on Windows 10 and it looks like Intellij IDEA is loading up all the names it finds in **C:\Windows\Fonts**. Perhaps that is what you would like NetBeans to do as well, but be mindful that selecting fonts from that list will not mean that the font will necessarily be available when your application runs in a browser of the user's choice on Android or macOS or iOS or Linux or some different version of Windows.

My own view is that NetBeans and Eclipse are doing the right thing, forcing you to think about what **family-name**(s) you want to specify, but others may feel differently.